# gfortran linker can't find a library -- but it is present

Tags: curl, libraries, gfortran, dynamic-linking, netcdf

I am trying to compile a Fortran code that needs netCDF and curl, among other things.  The library part of the command line looks like:

```
gfortran ... -L/usr/lib64 -lnetcdff -lnetcdf -lcurl -lz -lhdf5_fortran -lhdf5_hl -lhdf5
```

(Very sorry to skimp on details here, but this is work related and that is what I have to do.)

Am getting the error message:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcurl
```

But it is clearly present:

```
$> ls /usr/lib64 | grep curl
gpg2keys_curl
libcurl.so
libcurl.so.4
libcurl.so.4.1.1
libwsman_curl_client_transport.so.1
libwsman_curl_client_transport.so.1.0.0
```

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Aren't you compiling statically?

Comment: @VladimirF AFAICT gfortran has an option to specify static linking, but dynamic linking seems to be the default.  So as I understand it, I am compiling dynamically.  If I am wrong, feel free to enlighten me.